# Progress bar reset when button is re-clicked

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, android-progressbar, android-thread

This Code means that if I Click a button, a progress bar start 0 to 100%. And I want to make the progress bar reset, when I click a button before the progress bar reaches 100%.

Here is a part of my code.

This code is button listener.

```
public void Cal_btn(View v) {

    Message msg;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Square:
            if (Number.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "숫자를 입력하세요.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                pThread = new ProThread(pHandler);
                pThread.setDaemon(true);
                pThread.start();

                Cal_Result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                msg = new Message();
                msg.what = 1;
                msg.arg1 = Integer.parseInt(Number.getText().toString());
                mThread.mBackHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And this code is handler.

```
Handler pHandler = new Handler(){

    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if(msg.what == 3){
            if(msg.arg1 == 100){
                Cal_Result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                progress.setProgress(msg.arg1);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And this code is Thread run code.

```
class ProThread extends Thread{
    int proNum = 0;
    Handler pHandler;
    ProThread(Handler handler){
        pHandler = handler;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(proNum != 100) {
            proNum++;
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 3;
            msg.arg1 = proNum;
            pHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? First, you are starting ProThread in MainThread. It may block the MainThread. You need to check the concept and implement of "Handler/MessageQueue" again.

Comment: Try to disable button click once its clicks and reactive button click when progress bar reach 100%.

Comment: @yoonhok When I click a button before the progress bar reaches 100%, another progress bar start too. So two progress bars overlap, and first started progress bar do not stop.

Comment: @FahadEjazButt that is not way I want...

Comment: I already told you, you are starting the ProThread in MainThread directly.         
You should implement the runnable object and forward it in the handler like: Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(mRunnable);

Comment: new ProThread will always create new thread so you have either use Runnable interface or destroy previous thread before creating new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean member variable as a marker for "ProgressBar" started or not.

```
boolean isProgressBarRun;
```

When the button is clicked, change the status of this variable.
And if the button is clicked at first time, send a message.
And when you handle the message, re-send the messages every 10 ms in your "public void handleMessage(Message msg)" method.

And your onClick method can be written like below:

```
boolean isProgressBarRun = false;

...

public void Cal_btn(View v) {

    Message msg;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Square:
            if (Number.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "숫자를 입력하세요.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (isProgressBarRun) {
                    isProgressBarRun = false;
                    msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = 4; // to stop the progress bar
                    mThread.mBackHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    msg.what = 3;
                    msg.arg1 = Integer.parseInt(Number.getText().toString());
                    mThread.mBackHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                } else {
                    isProgressBarRun = true;
                    Cal_Result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    msg.arg1 = Integer.parseInt(Number.getText().toString());
                    mThread.mBackHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Your handler can be changed like below:

```
Handler pHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if(msg.what == 4){
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            progress.setProgress(msg.arg1);
            Message message = new Message();
            message .what = 3;
            message .arg1 = msg.arg1 + 1;
            pHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 10);
        }
    }
};
```

In summary, you don't need to implement Thread.
Upper codes are incorrect, just see the concept please.

Comment: I did not use your code, but I could understand what is the problem on my code. And I solved the problem well. Thank you for Teaching thread concept.